# How can I write in white ballpoint pen ink on black paper?

Tags: ink, pens

Are there white ink ballpoint pens (not felt or fountain pens) that write on black paper, in a way that is close to frictionless and noiseless, with ink that dries fast and won't blotch the paper?

Are there hues of white ink that are easily readable (high contrast) on white paper?

I prefer cheap, but good, factory-made white ink pens.

Here is a picture of the pens I want. I want ink ballpoint pens, not gel pens, which I believe are lower in quality, as they run out of ink quickly.

I love Schneider, Faber Castell / Corvina, and Bic pens:

[image: picture of mentioned pens]

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Maybe you can rewrite it so it becomes more clear what you are looking for (are you looking for a white or black pen? Do you want to write on white or black paper?)

Comment: Do you have a picture of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have boo picture of what I am trying to achieve.I want to write white or black on white or black.

Comment: You mean to say that you'd like a shade of off-white ink that'd still be visible on white paper as well as black paper?

Comment: No, I would like both. Thanks. Not sure what kind of media black paper would be, where I can find it. I wanted it for taking notes and starting diagrams, and see if it works. I doubt that any pen with white ink lasts very long, is equally expensive and runny without splodging as black, red, blue, and green ink.

Comment: [Black paper](https://www.google.com/search?q=black+paper) is easy to find at most art supply stores and even general stores, depending on your region.

Comment: Just a heads up, ballpoint pens are one of the worst things to write with. They require a lot of pressure to write, and usually cause lots of wrist pain. Rollerball are better, and fountain are the best for writing lots of stuff. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for product recommendation, which is [off-topic](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Joachim I think it’s _just_ about on the good side of [the line between material selection and product recommendation](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361/where-is-the-line-between-material-selection-and-product-recommendations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

White pens and colors are often used to lighten up the shade in art and crafts. Apart from that they have limited uses. As per your requirements, I would suggest you to either go for either a white gel pen or a marker. Unfortunately, ball point pens that have white ink are not easily available and they will not provide the results you are looking for.

My suggestion is to go with [Uni-Ball Signo Broad Gel Pen.](http://www.jetpens.com/Uni-ball-Signo-Broad-UM-153-Gel-Pen-White-Ink/pd/380)

Comment: From the description it looks like s good pen. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are many possible arts & crafts uses for white ink, so it's definitely possible to buy pens with white ink/paint. Look for a "gel" pen with white ink, and it should meet all the requirements that you have outlined.

Asking at your local arts & crafts store is the fastest way to find a good source of such implements, but there are also plenty of online suppliers (here is a [Guide to Choosing White Gel Pens and Markers](http://www.jetpens.com/blog/guide-to-choosing-white-gel-ink-pens-and-markers/pt/340) from one example).

Comment: What does "gel" exactly mean, and how is a "gel" pen different from those described in my post?

Comment: [Gel ink](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gel_pen) is higher viscosity than "regular" ballpoint ink, due to its different chemical composition. The physical components of a rollerball pen are the same whether it uses gel ink or not.

Comment: I've tried some gel pens and the ink sucked: it came out all at once, was not uniform, and didn't dry well, leaving smudges. Are any of the pens in the picture gel pens, as well?

Comment: Like anything, gel pens can vary significantly in quality depending on the manufacturer. I don't know whether your existing pens use gel ink or not -- you'd need to either ask the manufacturer, examine the package, or Google the specific model.

Comment: I personally have never had a problem using gel pens on black paper. They work great, are cheap enough that you can try multiple brands, and they are popular enough that you can find them at most stores that sell stationary supplies. Another suggestion would be to try the metallic sharpies. The silver one shows up really bright and clear on black paper.

Comment: What is a metallic sharpie, and what does sharpie stands for? Thanks.

Comment: [Sharpie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharpie_(marker)) is an extremely popular manufacturer of marker pens.  Metallic is one of their lines.  You can find them easily by plugging those two words into the search engine of your choice.

Comment: I agree, gel pens are great. The ink is thicker I guess, so they're really good for drawing over other dark colors. Artists like myself use them a lot when were doing really fine highlights on drawings and paintings because they are small, easy to control, and are opaque. I find that Gelly Roll are one of the best, and a white Posca 1MR (its paint though) also work very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you don't want gel pens, but I looked at various white ink pens for about 20 minutes, and there are literally no ballpoint pens with white ink. Ballpoint pens are also bad for writing. They require a lot of pressure, and the ink can be weird.

Gel pens are really good because they have smooth lines, and the ink is opaque, so it's nice and bright on the paper. I'm an artist, so white is a very important color. White gel pens are good to have because they are really easy to control and can do small details.

I would recommend Sakura Gelly Roll or Uni-Ball Signo White Gel Pens. I know that you said you used a gel pen before, and it didn't work well, but that pen might have been defective, damaged, or old. Try using some again to see what works.

Avoid using felt tip pens or paint pens when writing because they get used up fast and don't produce the cleanest lines. As for the black paper, lots of art and craft stores sell it, and you might also find a black paper notebook. Good luck with your pens!